# How to render React.CreatePortal component and a regular component in the same return statement

Tags: reactjs, components, portal

I am trying to run a component which runs 2 sub-components at the same time:

1. a subcomponent (Comp1) which renders inside a div called "divMenuElement"
2. a subcomponent (Comp2) which is rendered normally, and its visibility is based on a condition (showComp2)

This is my code:

```
    const menuNode = document.getElementById ("divMenuElement");
    let showComp2:boolean = true;
    
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(<Comp1/>,menuNode), 
           (showComp2 && <Comp2/>)
```

This code is not working, I tried several options, but they do not work for me.

How can I render it successfully?

Answer (score 1):

ReactDOM.createPortal returns something like ReactElement, so I think this may work.

```
return (
    <>
       {ReactDOM.createPortal(<Comp1/>,menuNode)} 
       {showComp2 && <Comp2/>}
    </>
 )
```